# Xamarin forms: How to access the toggled items id using OnToggledEvent

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a switch in my listview and I select some of the items like below screenshot.

[image]

I am trying to get the userids of the toggled item.
I try like below but getting an exception:

```
 public class MyToggledEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public UserProfileHBList MyItem { get; set; }
        public MyToggledEventArgs(UserProfileHBList item)
        {
            this.MyItem = item;
        }
    }

    void OnToggledEvent(object sender, MyToggledEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.MyItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Userid:>>"+item.userProfileTO.userId);
        }
    }
```

//Model class

```
public class DirectoryResponse
{
    public List<UserProfileHBList> userProfileHBList { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfileHBList
{
    public UserProfileTO userProfileTO { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfileTO
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any other way to get the userid?

Comment: Maybe you should use the Events every time that he press the switch(e.g. Toggled="OnToggledEvent", to trigger a function in codebehind and save the id).

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Comment: @AlanJonesRios For saving the id how can I use this Toggled property?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza  No viewmodel is created for this, only using xaml and xaml.cs files

Comment: @AlanJonesRios  I tried Toggled event Question edited with more details, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `OnToggledEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)` we can get the Parent `ViewCell` depending on your hierarchy:

```
public void OnToggledEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Here I use a Grid to wrap the content so I need to use two Parent to find the ViewCell
    ViewCell cell = (sender as Switch).Parent.Parent as ViewCell;

    // If you set the list<UserProfileHBList> as the ListView's ItemsSource, we can find the model through BindingContext
    UserProfileHBList model = cell.BindingContext as UserProfileHBList;

    // Then the userId can be known
    if (model != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Userid:>>"+model.userProfileTO.userId);
    }

}
```